# 2 TR seq fetch inside php loop how to fix?

Tags: php, html-table

html database col text like this
kalima another-kalima ACOUNTUNINCRHEX
 A             AA                                null
 C             BB                                null
 D             DD                               newline
 E             EE                                null

with current code give result
A C D 
E

any solution data comes in this way
A C D

(text box b/w tr tags) AA-BB-DD

E
(text box b/w tr tags) EE

and so...on

```
    while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    //counter is zero then we are start new row  
    $moon = $fetch['ACOUNTUNINCRHEX'];
        if ($i==0){
            echo '<tr align=center>';
        }

echo '<td align=center class=Astlye>'.$KALIMA.'</td>';

if ($i==!is_null($moon) OR $i>3){
            $i=0;
            echo '</tr>';    // <------ here is issue when new tr open it gives only value 4 alone instead of all 1,2,3,4 :( i know becaz of restrict with 'if' so thats why i wanted to know how to apply both conditions tr close also and new tr open give all id data
};
$i++; //$i = $i + 1 - counter + 1
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: what is this `$i==!is_null($moon)` condition  ?

Comment: this for closing tr ACOUNTUNINCRHEX = $moon

Comment: You don't need `$i>3` condition because while loop is checking if there are more rows or not  .Also, is there any reason to close `<tr>` if value of `$i >3` ?

Comment: pls check summary,, yes $i >3 limit no of col in tr tag